# What does plus (+) sign mean in openssl output Subject line?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm trying to self-sign an SSL certificate for testing purpose, where I need to match the `subject` of a real world certificate with a special subject line.

The certificates have a special `UID` attribute in their subject. For example if I inspect the certificate with `openssl`:

```
openssl x509 -in customer/1.user_cert.der -inform der -noout -text
```

Then in the output I can see a subject line like this:

```
        Subject: C = XX, CN = JOHN SMITH + UID = 123
```

Normally in the `Subject`, the comma `,` separates different fields, but here the CN and UID are separated by `+`.

I think the `+` is not part of `CN` because, if I try to self-create a certificate with `CN = JOHN + UID=123` then the `-text` output would show quotes (`"`) to indicate the boundaries of the CN like `CN = "JOHN + UID=123"`.

So what does this `+` mean in the subject line? How is it entered into a certificate request with openssl?

Comment: See [rfc4514](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4514) et pred. Note only OpenSSL 1.1.0 up defaults output to the standard (1779/2253/4514) syntax with separating commas; lower versions default to OpenSSL's own syntax with preceding slashes, still used (as you show) for `-subj` _input_, but you can change the output with `-nameopt rfc2253` or several variants, see the man page(s).

Answer (score 4):

It's a "Multivalue-RDN".

When creating a certificate request with multivalued RDN, `-multivalue-rdn` parameter must be given to the `openssl` command.

Example:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key user.key -multivalue-rdn -subj '/C=XX/CN=JOHN SMITH+UID=123/' -out user.csr
```

Reference:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/req.html

> -multivalue-rdn
>
> this option causes the -subj argument to be interpreted with full support for multivalued RDNs. Example:
>
> `/DC=org/DC=OpenSSL/DC=users/UID=123456+CN=John Doe`
>
> If -multi-rdn is not used then the UID value is 123456+CN=John Doe.